# Is it possible to loop a $request->hasFile() function and not get duplicate data?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to loop the `$request->hasFile()` function as part of an update module as such;

```php
foreach ($answers as $a) {
    $ansid = 0;
    $ansid = $a['id'];
    $ans['quiz_content'] = $data['quiz_content_'.$a['id']];
    $ans['quiz_is_answer'] = 0;
    if ($data['radio-group8'] == "radio-group8_".$a['id']) {
        $ans['quiz_is_answer'] = 1;
    }
    if ($request->hasFile('quiz_img_'.$ansid) && $data['quiz_content_'.$ansid] == null && !empty($data['quiz_img_'.$ansid])) {
        $project_image = $request->file('quiz_img_'.$ansid);
        $filename = $ansid.'answer'.time().'.'.$project_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/elearning/answers');
        $project_image->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        $ans['quiz_image_name'] = $filename;
        $ans['quiz_content_type'] = 2;
    } elseif ($request->hasFile('quiz_img_'.$ansid) && $data['quiz_content_'.$ansid] != null && !empty($data['quiz_img_'.$ansid])) {
        $project_image = $request->file('quiz_img_'.$ansid);
        $filename = $ansid.'answer'.time().'.'.$project_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/elearning/answers');
        $project_image->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        $ans['quiz_content'] = $data['quiz_content_'.$ansid];
        $ans['quiz_image_name'] = $filename;
        $ans['quiz_content_type'] = 3;
    }

    QuizOption::where('id', $ansid)->update($ans);
}
```

However, when I update my quiz options, say I have three options, a, b and c. If I set the image on a, b and c would get the same image and same content type. If I set the image on b, c would get the same image and content type as b. I know the issue lies with the `if($request->hasFile())` condition. but how do I code it so that each option, a, b and c, would have a unique answer and picture?

Comment: I think your problem might be in the first two lines insie the foreach loop. What do you really want: $ansid = 0; (to be an integer) or  $ansid = $a['id']; to be something from $answers? Btw. please show us some examples whats within $answers.

Comment: hey @PowerStat . basically, i thought the issue was with the id not resetting, hence the $ansid = 0; at the start. but, by adding $ans =[]; it works just fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing is actually related to how you're setting the `$ans` variable in the loop, not the `$request->hasFile()` call. Because you are never resetting the data inside `$ans` - only setting certain indexes - any data set during a conditional that doesn't match in future loops never changes.

Here is a simplified example of the issue ([view result on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Lf4iJ)):

```php
$data = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $data['id'] = $i;

    if ($i === 2) {
        $data['foobar'] = $i;
    }

    var_dump($data);
}
```

When the `if` conditional passes when `$i = 2`, it sets the `foobar` index on the array. None of the future loops change that index, or reset the `$data` array.

I'd suggest putting `$ans = [];` or a similar reset at the top of your loop, so each one gets fresh data related to only its answer.

Comment: so it's better to use a for loop instead of laravel's foreach loop? I shall try this out. thanks mate!

Comment: I just used `for` as an example to show you how setting the variable within a loop is affecting your code. Your `foreach` is fine. Please read the last sentence.

Comment: ahhh my bad, misunderstood it. so basically before i save the options i should push the values into a new array first yeah?

Comment: it works! resetting the array at the top as you said clears and gives me fresh data on each insert. I was struggling with this for 2 days and a simple line of code literally solved it. thanks a lot mate!